# Написала программу по поиску суммы в главной диагонали, но первый элемент не считает

Tags: c++

Добрый день) написала программу по поиску суммы в главной диагонали. она работает, но как всегда не так как я хочу. программа просто не учитывает первый элемент главной диагонали. матрица простая 3*3 вот код

```
void gdia()
{
    gdia_sum=0;
    for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; ++j)
            if (i=j)
            gdia_sum+=mas[i][j];
            cout<<"Summa elementov glavmoy diagonali = "<<gdia_sum<<endl;
    }
}
```

и если не трудно как найти сумму только уже побочной диагонали?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала код хорошо бы отформатировать и понять, что он делает

```
void gdia()
{
    gdia_sum=0;
    for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; ++j)
            if (i=j)
                gdia_sum+=mas[i][j];
        cout<<"Summa elementov glavmoy diagonali = "<<gdia_sum<<endl;
    }
}
```

Из этого следует, что код суммирует элементы (и похоже все), но только выводит результаты  после обработки каждой строки (то есть, он у Вас должен выводить как минимум 3 раза.) Но там закралась ещё одна ошибка. (если компилятор, который Вы используете о ней ничего не написал - попросите поменять компилятор!). В условиях "равно" записывается в виде `==`. Конечно, специалисты могут писать и с одиночным равно, но это не для начинающих.

Исправленный код должен выглядеть как минимум так (это не идеальный и не самый красивый и быстрый код)

```
void gdia()
{
    gdia_sum=0;
    for(i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        for(j=0; j<n; ++j) {
            if (i==j) {
                gdia_sum+=mas[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"Summa elementov glavmoy diagonali = "<<gdia_sum<<endl;
}
```

На первый порах фигурные скобки лучше писать всегда.

Для того, что бы перейти к побочной диагонали, нужно просто проработать условие. Для этого для начала просто запишем пары координат.

```
0,2
1,1
2,0
```

Не сложно заметить, что их сумма всегда на единичку меньше размера матрицы (настойчиво рекомендую потренироваться на других матрицах).

Поэтому, условие (`i==j`) заменяется на другое `i+j+1 == n`;

Но можно код для суммирования главной диагонали записать и лучше.

```
void gdia()
{
    gdia_sum=0;
    for(i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        gdia_sum+=mas[i][i];
    }
    cout<<"Summa elementov glavmoy diagonali = "<<gdia_sum<<endl;
}
```

так как координаты одинаковые, и главная диагональ суть вектор (одномерный массив), то и цикл нужен один. Для суммирования побочной диагонали нужно сделать одну маленькую замену в `mas[i][i]`. А вот какую - это уже домашнее задание. Выше для этого есть все объяснения.

Comment: @KoVadim Огромное Вам спасибо за подробное разъяснения

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
long n;

do {
    cout << "Input n = " << " ";
} while (cin >> n && (n < 0 || n > 15));

int A[n][n];
int i, j, sum = 0, k = 0;

cout << "Enter the matrix\n";

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        A[i][j]=rand()%10;
        cout << A[i][j] << " ";}
    cout << endl;
}

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (i == j)
        {
            sum += A[i][i];
        }
    }
cout << endl<<"Sum= "<< sum;

return 0;
}
```